Angular - route to first available child route
This is my current router config. My desired behaviour is to redirect to the first available child route. So for example, if child1 cannot be accessed due to the route guard, it should attempt to load child2. Originally, I had this code that just redirected to child1, but this fails if child1 is not accessible.
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'child1',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child1',
        component: Child1Component,
        canActivate: [routeGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'child2',
        component: Child2Component,
        canActivate: [routeGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'child3',
        component: Child3Component,
        canActivate: [routeGuard],
      },
    ],
  },
];


I am not sure if you can automatically redirect the first available child route.
But you can create a set of functions and call it from the parent component, if the function returns true then redirect to that child component corresponding to that function
export function guardCondition1(){
  // implement your logic here
  return false
}

export function guardCondition2(){
  // implement your logic here
  return true
}
export function guardCondition3(){
  // implement your logic here
  return false
}

In the ngOnit of the parent component call the functions. You can also set the order in the routeGuards array
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
   routeGuards=[guardCondition1,guardCondition2,guardCondition3]
   activatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
   router = inject(Router)

  ngOnInit(): void {

     for(let key in this.routeGuards){
       const navigateToChild  =this.routeGuards[key]();
       // implement your logic here
       if(navigateToChild){
         this.router.navigateByUrl('child2');
         break;
       }
     }
   }
}


Yeah this might be the only way. Maybe I could even do this by looping through the routes array itself if I exported it keep the route guards defined in a single place
